# Bad Authentication Data 215 - Twitter4J 2.2.6

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I've encountered this problem recently after releasing my app in GooglePlay. It seems that Twitter has changed their API or configuration without having legacy compatibility. I'm using Twitter4J 2.2.6.
This is a ref link about this problem but there is no solution. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12782

```
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576): 400:The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why. This is the status code that will be returned during rate limiting (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting).
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576): {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=6f0f59ca or
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=3bea4a0a
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[6f0f59ca-3bea4a0a], statusCode=400, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.6}
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:185)
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:93)
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576):     at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.fillInIDAndScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:135)
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.verifyCredentials(TwitterImpl.java:1084)
12-13 11:54:53.872: W/System.err(6576):     at app.jp.cropnet.twitter.TwitterApp$3.run(TwitterApp.java:255)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use twitter4j 2.1.1 instead of 2.2.6 there's some troubles with this version or have a look on this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) 2.2.6 is used and it works perfectly